# Finding closed form expression for $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\left( e^{-n(n-1)} - e^{-n(n+1)}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function

I want to find a closed form expression for:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\left( e^{-n(n-1)} - e^{-n(n+1)}\right)$$

This isn't a homework problem, more of something that emerged as a side problem from other work. This expression will converge and I was trying to find a closed form expression for the value but I'm kind of struggling.

Any help?

Comment: This is for all users: try to include your question in the body as well, because in the IOS application, formulas do not appear in the title.

Comment: Thank you, will keep that in mind!

Comment: Have you tried using L'Hospital's rule after rewriting it accordingly..

Comment: $n \to \infty$?

Comment: If you write the summation, then you have a series, not a sequence.

Comment: Yeah, messed up writing the question, apologies! Should I just post it new or change the tags?

Comment: Hint: Take 2 adjacent terms, it reduces to a telescopic series..

Comment: ^Thanks for the hint, I'm going to try and solve it!

Answer (score 2):

First notice that

$$
S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(e^{-n(n-1)} -e^{-n(n+1)}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ne^{-n(n-1)}  - \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(k-1)e^{-k(k-1)} 
$$
where we made $n=k-1$, hence we get

$$
S = 1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}e^{-n^2 +n}
$$
This last sum can be evaluated using the Jacobi theta function $\vartheta$. Finally we obtain the closed form

$$
S = \frac{1}{2} e^{1/4} \vartheta_2 (0, \frac{1}{e}) = 1.137820181\cdots
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ n\left( e^{-n(n-1)} - e^{-n(n+1)}\right) = n\left( \frac{1}{e^{n(n-1)}} - \frac{1}{e^{n(n+1)}} \right) = n\left( \frac{e^{n(n+1)} - e^{n(n-1)}}{e^{2n^2}} \right) = \frac{n\left(e^{n} - e^{-n} \right)}{e^{n^2}}$$

The series of that general term converges using the $n^\alpha$ test, which states that if the limit of $n^{\alpha}$ multiplied by the general term of a nonnegative series is zero, and $\alpha >1$, then the series converges.

We can multiply our series by any $n^{\alpha}$ we wish. $n^{100}$ for instance, and we'll still have a zero limit.

Comment: I want to accept your answer cause I messed up the question initially. Sorry :(

Comment: I'll edit my answer to answer your new question.

Comment: I didn't downvote that, my mistake for messing up the question.

Answer (score 0):

$\left|n\left(e^{-n(n-1)}-e^{-n(n+1)}\right)\right|=\left|n\left(\dfrac{1}{e^{n(n-1)}}-\dfrac{1}{e^{n(n+1)}}\right)\right|=n\cdot\dfrac{e^{n(n+1)}-e^{n(n-1)}}{e^{2n^2}}<\dfrac{2ne^{n(n+1)}}{e^{2n^2}}=2ne^{n-n^2}=\dfrac{2n}{e^{n^2-n}}< \dfrac{2n}{1+(n^2-n)+\dfrac{(n^2-n)^2}{2}}< \dfrac{4n}{(n^2-n)^2}<\dfrac{16}{n^3}$. Thus the series converges absolutely by comparison test with the convergent $p$ series with $p = 3$. I might answer the "wrong" question, but seem "satisfied" by my own answer....